# Rotate image -45 degrees

Tags: swift

I am building example about **FloatingButton**.

But I have some troubles with rotate image. I want it to rotate like this link

https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton

But my button is:

[image]

As you can see, when I click the first time, it run well :D, it transform like `x`, but when I click again, I want it back to original like `+`, but it doesn't work well.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var floatingButton: UIImageView!
    var floatingButtonIsActive = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addShadowToFloatingButton()
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(floatingButtonTapped(_:)))
        floatingButton.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    private func addShadowToFloatingButton() {
        floatingButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        floatingButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2, height: 2)
        floatingButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        floatingButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    }

    func floatingButtonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if floatingButtonIsActive == false {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.floatingButtonIsActive = true
            })

        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_4))
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.floatingButtonIsActive = false
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can again rotate to 45 degree. It will have thw same effect. self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))

Comment: No, it won't work like you said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the transform to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` when you are done. That is the transform that it originally had. When you set the transform, you are telling it the absolute angle to rotate to, regardless of what angle it is currently at.

```
func floatingButtonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if floatingButtonIsActive == false {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.floatingButtonIsActive = true
        })

    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.floatingButtonIsActive = false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This will rotate button to right, if someone wants to rotate it to left use negative value: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))` and M_PI_4 is deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**:

for 180" rotation:

```
self.yourLayerName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
```

for returning to default position:

```
self.yourLayerName.transform = .identity
```

For changing the rotation angle you can multiply or division "pi" number.

for 45" rotation you need to implement below :

```
self.yourLayerName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/4))
```